# What is the blue material on this PCB? Why is it used?

Tags: pcb, power-electronics, high-voltage

This is a tear down of a medical stimulator. I see blue colored potting on the PCB. I really don't understand what it is.  Does anyone know?

[image]

Comment: I don't think anyone can identify what the material definitely is. It is just some potting compound. Used to maybe prevent reverse engineering of the product, maybe for extra insulation too but it is unknown if those are high voltage section or not.

Comment: Yes that area is for high voltage. It produces some 60V or 100V over there. @Justme

Comment: I think Justme is correct when he says it's for protection from some moderately high voltage (over 48 VDC), especially given Ram's comment.  And I do not see any sort of interlock that would prevent this unit from being powered when the cover is removed.

Answer (score 4):

This is either a [conformal coating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_coating) or [potting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potting_(electronics)) material. They are used for various purposes such as high voltage insulation, moisture resistance, protection from dirt, dust and chemicals, and vibration dampening.

Both potting and conformal coatings can use the same materials, such as silicone, polyurethane, acrylic and epoxy, but potting is a much thicker coating meant to protect from impact or deter reverse engineering a product whereas a conformal coating is thinner, mostly meant for protection from environmental conditions.

Being that this is a medical stimulator, in this case it's probably being used for high voltage protection.

Comment: Never seen a partially-applied conformal coating.

Comment: I don't think it's a conformal coating.  More like a potting compound.  Most conformal coatings allow for rework of the board.  That would be very difficult with this material.  But I do agree that whatever it is it's there for protection from high voltages.

Comment: Conformal is thinner, potting is thicker, this is probably somewhere in the middle. Answer edited.

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers, it's difficult to remove, I tried. It's look like potting compound.